# Mounting second drive with corrupted sectors, common techniques not working

Tags: 16.04, mount, drive

Ubuntu 16.04.1

This laptop has two physical disks, when logged into Ubuntu on one drive, cannot view the other drive, the one with windows.

Unable to access “499 GB Volume”

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb4 at /media/chuck/DA2AFEDB2AFEB41B: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb4" "/media/chuck/DA2AFEDB2AFEB41B"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

so tried `fdisk -l`, which I think is fixed disk list, and it sees the linux disk and it sees the windows disk:

```
chuck@chuck-Satellite-P875:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for chuck: 
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

and then it shows a bunch of stuff including the linux drive as /dev/sda, with /dev/sda1 thru /dev/sda6
then the windows drive as /dev/sbd with /dev/sbd1 thru /dev/sbd5

so linux can see the windows drive, right?

```
chuck@chuck-Satellite-P875:~$ sudo mount /dev/sbd /mnt
mount: special device /dev/sbd does not exist
chuck@chuck-Satellite-P875:~$ sudo mount /dev/sbd1 /mnt
mount: special device /dev/sbd1 does not exist
...
chuck@chuck-Satellite-P875:~$ sudo mount /dev/sbd5 /mnt
mount: special device /dev/sbd5 does not exist
```

do I need to tell it sbd1 is in sbd? how?

I have some UUIDs, is there some way to use those?

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="0100-3191" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ea9dff67-090e-4637-923a-a6d0e530e030"
/dev/sda2: PARTUUID="c60843f8-0b09-4a45-a42c-ac4574634996"
/dev/sda3: UUID="d667b884-df12-47a1-bc7b-219c2d9bd01f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1329343c-d4d3-40c6-b8c9-2b231994557d"
/dev/sda4: PARTUUID="16c1bd1f-7819-4975-b6ce-644f73ff34d7"
/dev/sda5: UUID="cca8b76c-6942-4330-9e2d-469ef9524bed" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="afa9ac42-348b-4440-9b73-0435512a725e"
/dev/sda6: UUID="34fff9a0-94d1-4ede-a9a1-8d151f2490f3" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="b8d3384b-de5a-4965-b0c0-e16f8b9e75cc"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="C8CEFA02CEF9E918" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e566bf90-36a6-48f9-acd0-03f676d33345"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="BCFB-E073" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="c0a5152f-7788-4ac6-81ab-f920efc93139"
/dev/sdb3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="7607b4f9-4021-4b9b-9b8d-b5faf541ec7f"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="DA2AFEDB2AFEB41B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e0c362d3-b65a-4e4f-a701-1bc594042d43"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="32CAE475CAE436AF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5ed526c0-d59f-4753-9e2a-0e61ac448b97"
```

Note, all of this is because AVG antivirus software tried to upgrade itself to the full "360" version and it hangs loading and will not let the windows load begin. AVG says to start windows in safe mode and uninstall, but getting windows to start appears to be not possible. I was going to open the windows drive from ubuntu and either retrieve as many files as possible or just keep deleting AVG folders until windows was able to start.

Can provide lots more detail if anybody is wants to see it.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If filesystem is healthy then Ubuntu should be able to mount the drive.

In current situation i would just run `chkdsk /R /F` for this disk in Windows environment, for example you could use MiniXP on Hirens boot cd. Then you sohuld be able to mount the disk.

But as this is not Windows forum i should also sugest some Ubuntu tools to fix the filesystem...

First install NTFS-3G by typing this command:

`sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`

Next install NTFSProgs in the same way:

`sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`

Now with both of those tools at your disposal, you can set about fixing Windows. First locate your Windows partition. In the Terminal type:

`sudo fdisk -l`

Armed with this information you want to use NTFSProgs to attempt to fix the partition. In your Terminal window type:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/<device name>`

Comment: tyvm for the help. Am trying the ubuntu one first, got this:

Comment: got it working. longish story. message if anybody needs to hear it. Tyvm Taavi.